# SQL Server: Enforce value on column for INSERT or UPDATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, database-trigger

In SQL Server, I am looking for a trigger to enforce certain values in 'create' and 'last_update' columns. These would be for 'create_time', 'create_user', 'last_update_time', and 'last_update_user'.

On INSERT, I want to enforce the following:

```
'create_time' = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
'create_user' = CURRENT_USER
'last_update_time' = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
'last_update_user' = CURRENT_USER
```

On UPDATE, I want to enforce the following:

```
'create_time' = <unchanged>
'create_user' = <unchanged>
'last_update_time' = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
'last_update_user' = CURRENT_USER'
```

How would I enforce this, and in what location would this be placed? Would this be in the DDL, stored procedures, or elsewhere?

Comment: You could put a default on create time and last update time so when a record is inserted it will default to the current date/time for both those columns.  For when the record is updated you will have to set that in the update statement.  For the user that depends on what you mean by user?  The user that is using your application (then you would have to pass this as a paramater to the query/Stored Procedure?  Or the user that is executing the code in SQL?

Comment: Hi Brad, thank you very much for the reply. 
-The default is certainly a possibility. Is there a way this can override a value if the user attempts to insert something different?
-To be clear, the user would the be user executing the code in SQL

Comment: You might read about `INSTEAD OF TRIGGER`, but there are backdraws too...

Comment: You dont want the user to insert a date you want to force what is inserted?  Then in your code/Stored Procedure do not give the the opportunity to do so, just hard code the value as GetDate() for the current date.  To grab the user that is executing the script I beleive you can use SELECT CURRENT_USER, if your app has a user and you want to use that you will have to pass that to the code